# Is it possible to access the main window of a release-built Electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to access the main window JavaScript context of an Electron application.

This is easy in development:

- `npm install electron --save-dev`
- `electron index.js --inspect`
- Go to `chrome://inspect` and open the DevTools
- In the DevTools console, run `require('electron')` and voila

However, after distributing the application, which I do by using the prebuilt Electron binaries and placing my files in `resources/app` as described in [Manual Distribution](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-distribution#manual-distribution), the `require` call is no longer available in the attached debugger.

`electron --inspect` still works and the debugger is attached and listening. The DevTools can also connect and I can see globals (like `process`), but the `require` global is no longer there.

I don't have experience with release builds of Electron, is this global stripped forever? Would I have to build my own Electron binary and somehow configure it to stay in?

Is it possible, with an already built app, to access the `require` global some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A gentleman in the Electron repository helped me out in [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18334) I posted.

Indeed `require` not being available at the global level seems to be by design, but there is a way to obtain a reference to the `require` function:

```
process.mainModule.require
```

This worked perfectly well for me both in `npx electron --inspect` and when running built Electron with the `--inspect` flag.